# Missing copy button in new version of Remix

Tags: ethereum, remix

I can't see the button to copy the selected ethereum addresses in the new version. why is that?
As you can see the ethereum addresses are masked 0xCA3....
I want to copy them using a button. Like the button that has the previous version. But in the new version the button is missing.

Is there a way to copy the address without browsing the logs?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the buttons on both my firefox and chrome.

Try to upgrade your browser to the latest version.

[image]